# 220 v power adapter plug for inspiron mini 10

Tags: power-supply, power

I have a US Dell Inspiron Mini 10 and I'm travelling to a European country that has 220 v power.  How do I find out if I just need the adapter plug or if I need to have a power converter from 220 to 110 as well?  The 3 prong plug that came with the mini says Input 100-240v so I'm assuming I can just plug it into the adapter for that country (even if there are only 2 prongs)?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I find out if I just need the adapter plug or if I need to have a power converter from 220 to 110 as well?

You said it.

> The 3 prong plug that came with the mini says Input 100-240v

---

> so I'm assuming I can just plug it into the adapter for that country (even if there are only 2 prongs)?

Yes

Answer (score 1):

Modern switched mode power supplies are generally capable of coping with any voltage from around 100 to 240 volts.  Older PSUs built in to computers often had a 240/110 volt switch (many a time I've had to replace one because the owner switched it to 110v in the UK and blew it up...) but those have been dropped in favour of auto-switching.

As long as the label on the power supply looks something like this:

[image]

(note the **INPUT** line - **100-240V** ~ 1.5A(1,5A) 50-60Hz) then you should be perfectly fine to use this power adapter in any country.  If you are thinking of traveling to the UK frequently it may be worth investing in a UK power cable portion of the adapter (just the thick cable that goes between the wall and the power adapter) to save using socket adapters all the time.